# Recover MySQL ibdata1 file

Tags: mysql, innodb

I had mysql running on my VPS. Today it crashed for no good reason!

I tried `service mysql start`, it gave me `start: Job failed to start`.

First thing I did was to backup `/var/lib/mysql` which contained folders corresponding to my databases and these other files:

- `debian-5.5.flag`
- `ibdata1`
- `ib_logfile0`
- `ib_logfile1`
- `mysql_upgrade_info`

I removed `/etc/mysql` and did `sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-common` and then installed everything again, the result was the same: `start: Job failed to start`.

I went to `/var/lib/mysql/` and deleted `ib*` files. I could start mysql then, but some of the tables were problematic: I could see their names in PhpMyAdmin, but when tried to run queries, mysql errored out that the table doesn't exist.

I assume `ibdata1` is corrupted! I put `innodb_force_recovery = 0` and tried it upto `innodb_force_recovery = 6`, none of them worked and I got the same error when I tried to start mysql.

I still have the whole `/var/lib/mysql` backup.

Any ideas why this happened and how I can recover the data and start mysql again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end `mysqld --innodb_force_recovery=1` did the trick! Still don't know why it wasn't reading `innodb_force_recovery=1` from the config files. But passing the argument directly to the `mysqld` worked!

Answer (score 1):

What You make right - it is backup all files from /var/lib/mysql

all other steps - wrong

Your current error (in PHPMyAdmin with phantom tables) - because You have Your database folder with .frm files for table structure, and empty (new) ibdata.

What You can do now - revert all back (restore files in it original place)
Then You can:
- check error log file, for error message
- start change innodb_force_recovery from 1 to 6

Comment: Thanks :) I already have checked the log files! nothing useful there when I changed `innodb_force_recovery`. I suspected `mysqld` doesn't read `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, i ran `mysqld --innodb_force_recovery=1` and it worked!! Thanks anyway, you kind of pointed me into the right direction.
Still no idea why it crashed in the first place, and why it doesn't care about `my.cnf`.